# Python testing a class

Tags: python, unit-testing

Using a simple class with a lot work for initialization:

```
class MyClass():

    def __init__(self, attr1, attr2):

        self._init_method1(attr1)
        self._init_method2(attr2)
        self._init_method3

    def _init_method1(self, attr1)
    ...
...
```

I tried to use unittest2 to test the `_init_method`s which do some calculations:

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.my_class = MyClass(ATTR1, ATTR2)

    def test_init_method1(self):
    ...

    def test_init_method2(self):
    ...
```

Doing it this way is not appropriate: If any of the test_init methods fail, *every* will fail as the `setUp` method fails.

1. What is the standard way to tackle this problem?
2. How should I design my unittests to be able to encapsulate the
   tests?
3. Or is there an error in my class design?

Comment: This is not inappropriate - it seems quite logical, that if the object cannot be constructed it cannot be tested, by ANY of the test methods. So all should fail, because their assertions are unverifiable - thus it should be assumed that they don't pass.

Comment: I am writing a parser. Those init methods mainly search for some elements in the document and transform them. I would like to test those method's logic. It seems a little odd to me to write testcases on methods that already have been executed in setUp

Comment: I see. Seems to me a design flaw then. If you'd approach this using TDD, you'd get a different architecture - definitely "business" logic wouldn't be in the constructor.

Comment: Where else would I put functions which calculate properties only once (so `@property` is not an option) The user of this class should not be bothered by all this business logic inside

Comment: It's hard to guess without a precise problem statement, but I'm guessing that this could end up in a different class. So your current `MyClass` would accept interfaces of these "calculation" classes. It would call their method to "calculate" what's needed only once - in the constructor. These classes could be unit-tested separately (and you would test their "calculate" method - so no "logic in constructor" problem). Testing of `MyClass` would've also been easier, because you'd just inject results of the "calculator" classes, and test only the methods of `MyClass` - using these results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an instance of `MyClass` without calling `MyClass.__init__`, by calling the static method `MyClass.__new__` directly, with the class itself as the first argument.

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.my_class = MyClass.__new__(MyClass)

    def test_init_method1(self):
        attr1 = ...
        result = self.my_class._init_method1(attr1)
```

---

When you call `x = MyClass(attr1, attr2)`, it is roughly equivalent to:

```
x = MyClass.__init__( MyClass.__new__(MyClass, attr1, attr2),
                      attr1,
                      attr2 )
```

Comment: Indeed in this context it does solve OP's problem, but it's not a good practice. The design is flawed (so much logic in the constructor is inappropriate for the use case described by the OP in the comment under the question). I'm giving -1 just to be honest - no hard feelings I hope :)

Comment: So what exactly is wrong with the answer, given the constraints imposed by the question? More importantly, how would you improve it?

Comment: Instead of this hack I'd suggest fixing the design - I've suggested the solution in the comments. Just don't have the time to compose a complete answer. This is just a workaround that doesn't deal with the problem itself - in other languages it's not that easy to bypass the constructor.

Comment: What do other languages have to do with Python code? Python explicitly separates object creation from object initialization; I see no reason not to take advantage of that. Also, my answer shows a valid technique for *testing* (I wouldn't advocate using this in production code), whether or not the class it is testing is well-designed.

Comment: The point of the problem is irrelevant of the language. It can be solved accidentally in this manner only because accidentally it's Python. IMHO it is not a valid technique for *testing*. One of main merits of unit tests is that they force good design. In this example, we avoid fixing the design to accommodate better tests using a workaround not "available" in unit-testing in general. While I agree that this is a solution to this particular problem (and an interesting one - I didn't know one can do this :) ), it doesn't show the right way to deal with the core of the problem.

Comment: Breaking the `__init__` method into several functions is not by itself broken design. The OP may be doing it unnecessarily, but that has nothing to do with my answer.

Comment: I may be repeating myself but: the point of the whole issue is that there are non-testable methods. The non-testability is the result of the wrong design. Your answer doesn't address this issue, but just shows a workaround. IMHO that's the wrong way to go, it's just sweeping the problem under the carpet.